# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when deploying ASP.NET 4.5 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 MVC application written in C#. I'm using VS 2019. I have successfully deployed this project in the past, but this time, after I publish and move the code to the server, I am getting the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
> AI.Controllers.HomeController.Index() +174
> lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +86
> System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +228   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +34
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +38
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +69   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +71   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +387   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +38   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

Version Information:

- Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
- ASP.NET Version:4.7.3770.0

The application works fine when I run it in debug mode in VS2019; I only get this error after I deploy. I can't set any breakpoints or find out what might be wrong in the deployed code, and the stack trace doesn't tell me where my error is either -- if the "+174" is supposed to be a line number in the source code, that's the last line in the file.

The second line in the stack trace is lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +86 but there are no lambda expressions in the c# of the HomeController.sc file, so that seems to be a red herring as well.

Here is the complete code in my HomeController.cs file:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using AI.auth;
using AI.util;
using AI.Models;

namespace AI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public class AjaxRequestAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
        {
            public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
            {
                return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
            }
        }

        protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, Encoding contentEncoding, JsonRequestBehavior behavior)
        {
            return new JsonNetResult
            {
                Data = data,
                ContentType = contentType,
                ContentEncoding = contentEncoding,
                JsonRequestBehavior = behavior
            };
        }

        public ActionResult TestBlank() // can be removed after testing
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/PageNotFound.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //do initial routing and authorization
            bool thereAreClaims = false;

            UserContext uc = new UserContext();

            User thisUser = (User)Session["userInfo"];
            if (thisUser.ACCESS_ID == "") { return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "NotAuthorized" }); }

            //if (thisUser.ut.IS_STUDENT)
            //{
            thereAreClaims = StudentContext.checkClaims(thisUser.ACCESS_ID);
            //}
            if (thereAreClaims) { thisUser.ut.IS_STUDENT = true; }

            if (thisUser.ut.IS_ADMIN)
            {
                return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Admin", action = "Claims" }); // need to get action_security when we get there.
            }
            else
            {
                if (thisUser.ut.IS_STUDENT)
                {
                    if (thisUser.ut.IS_EDUCATOR) // 
                    {

                        if (thereAreClaims)
                        {
                            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "GettingStarted" }); // choice page
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Educator", action = "GettingStarted" }); // need to get action_security when we get there.
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (thereAreClaims)
                        {
                            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Student", action = "GettingStarted" }); // need to get action_security when we get there.
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "NoClaimsStudent" });
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (thisUser.ut.IS_EDUCATOR)
                    {
                        return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Educator", action = "GettingStarted" }); // need to get action_security when we get there.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "NotAuthorized" });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // GET: /Home/NotAuthorized
        public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoAuth.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult NotAuthorizedStudent() 
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoAuthStudent.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult NotAuthorizedEducator() 
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoAuthEducator.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult NotAuthorizedToDownload()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoAuthViewDoc.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult FileNotFound()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoFile.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult NoClaimsStudent()  // but this one *should* have the photo
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/NoClaimsStudent.cshtml");
        }

        //[AuthorizeView]
        public ActionResult GettingStarted() 
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Choice.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult PageNotFound()
        {
            return View("~/Views/Shared/PageNotFound.cshtml");
        }

        public ActionResult UnMask()
        {
            string action_data = "Home/UnMask";
            GlobalConfigContext gcc = new GlobalConfigContext();
            GlobalConfig gc = gcc.getGlobalConfig();
            if ((bool)Session["impersonate"] && (string)Session["orig_access_id"] != "" )
            {
                UserContext uc = new UserContext();
                User unMasked = uc.getUserInfo((string)Session["orig_access_id"]);

                if (unMasked.CAN_IMPERSONATE)
                {
                    Session["impersonate"] = false;
                    Session["orig_access_id"] = "";
                    Session["userInfo"] = (User)unMasked;
                    Session["username"] = (string)unMasked.ACCESS_ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    LoggingContext.Log("Unauthorized access to page", action_data, unMasked.ACCESS_ID);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LoggingContext.Log("Invalid attempt to impersonate", action_data, (string)Session["orig_access_id"]);
            }

            return RedirectToRoute(new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        }

        public void logtest ()
        {
             LoggingContext.Log("Logtest", "Home/Logtest", (string)Session["username"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for how to debug this problem? Is it possible that it is a problem with .net versioning? The target version in the VS project is 4.5 so I'm not sure where the Version:4.7.3770.0 is coming from.Thanks for any suggestions

BTW: I looked at [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) but the problem is that I am unable to debug after deployment and in debug mode it works fine

Comment: What's on line 174?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 has been out of support for 5 years. Have you considered upgrading to .NET Framework 4.8? It's a pretty easy upgrade. Have you tried deploying your app in Debug configuration instead of Release to get more info? One potential source of error is: `User thisUser = (User)Session["userInfo"];` If you access any property of `thisUser` such as `ACCESS_ID` when `thisUser` is null, you'll get the error you got.

Comment: @Fildor thanks -- I have looked through the suggested question but didn't find anything. Line 174 is the very last (empty) line of the HomeController.cs file -- there's an extra carriage return after the curly brace that closes the namespace block.

Comment: If nothing else, add some logs to the db or file somewhere and see. It looks like you're taking the existence of data for granted in some cases; add some logs around those. Or...just guard your code against NREs and deal with them.

Comment: @mason, thanks. I tried upgrading to .net 4.7 but it told me that I had a nuget package (DocumentFormat.OpenXML) that was not compatible and I was unable to install a newer version than 2.12.3. Session["userinfo"] is populated in global.asax Sesssion_Start. But I will look at that because the authentication on the server is different than in local machine debug mode. But I didn't change anything about that part of the code, so I am not hopeful.

Comment: Running into a single error when trying to upgrade to newer .NET Framework isn't really a good excuse not to upgrade. .NET Framework 4.5 has been [out of support for 5 years](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/). **It's not receiving security updates**, it's not getting feature improvements or bug fixes or anything. There's really not a good excuse to still be on 4.5. There is a [stable version of DocumentFormat.OpenXML](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/2.12.3) that runs on newer .NET Frameworks.

Comment: I found the problem. It was indeed an issue with Session["userinfo"] being null. There was some badly written code that didn't populate that session variable in this particular server environment. Thanks for your help. @mason we are in the process of rewriting all of our apps in .NET5 (core), but we are a two person shop with more than 20 legacy webapps to maintain so it will take us awhile. But I can do a little more work and at least get this one to 4.8 -- thanks for your help.